# MigLayout with full screen mode

Tags: java, fullscreen, resolution, miglayout

My application uses the full screen mode automatically when it launches, and it displays correctly with `1024x768` resolution, but when I have tested the same app in `1366x768` the bottom part disappears. the full screen mode setting looks like this :

```
//*********************  Full Screen Parameter  *****************
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), tk.getScreenSize()));
setUndecorated(true);
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: A screenshot and an example showing how the layout is used would probably help understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setLocation()? For example

```
setLocation(0,0);
setSize(tk.getScreenSize());
setUndecorated(true);
setVisible(true);
```